# Display Dialogfragment with Fragment

Tags: java, android

I have an activity. There is a `TableLayout` in the activity. The pages in the `TableLayout` contain `Fragment`s. I want it to be opened as a fragment in dialog in the edit event of the fragment in the fragment.

shortly : `Fragment` in fragment show `Dialogfragment`

```
firsatulke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DialogFragment();
            dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"f_ulkeListe");
        }
    });
```

Error :

Error:(123, 31) error: no suitable method found for show(android.app.FragmentManager,String)
method DialogFragment.show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager)
method DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to FragmentTransaction)

Problem solved friends. Updated code ;

```
dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"f_ulkeListe");
```

Comment: What you are asking is possible. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for updating the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`.